# Matplotlib | OpenCV | Memory Optimization

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I need to extract some features for my deep learning project. To do so, I need to convert an array of signals (ECG signals) to figures using Matplotlib, then resize them (224*224*3) using OpenCV, and finally save the final figures in a folder as well as in a list. I have around 100,000 figures. Unfortunately, I face an issue with the memory and ultimately my system stops working. Is there any approach to improve the code? Thank you

```
train_x = []
train_y=[]

for i in range (0, len(features_train[0])):
    filename = "./Train/"+ str(i) + ".png"

    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.plot(features_train[0][i])
    plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
    for spine in plt.gca().spines.values():
         spine.set_visible(False)
    fig.savefig(filename, dpi=fig.dpi)
    plt.close(fig)

    im_gray = cv2.imread(filename, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    im_gray = cv2.resize(im_gray, (224, 224))
    cv2.imwrite(filename, im_gray)
    v= cv2.imread (filename)
    train_x.append(v)
    train_y.append (features_train[1][i])

train_x = np.asarray(train_x)
train_y = np.asarray(train_y)
pickle.dump( train_x, open( "train_x.p", "wb" ) )
pickle.dump( train_y, open( "train_y.p", "wb" ) )
```

Comment: I don't understand why you would do so many `imread` and the `imwrite`. You can set the figure size and color when saving the image in the step `fig.savefig`

Comment: Split the training data into batches that are small enough to fit in the memory you've got available. You can also split the processing into several stages -- one script to generate the charts, one to make `train_x.p`, one to make `train_y.p`...